# PhpStorm 2016.2.1 bug when creating new project from excisting files

Tags: phpstorm

Hard to explain, better watch this video: [PhpStorm 2016.2.1 bug when creating new project from excisting filese](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3_onkuNV2A)

And this happening only with this project files! Other projects seams creating without issues.

`2016-07-31 16:34:55,222 [11533661]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.AutoUploadComponent.getInstance(AutoUploadComponent.java:59)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.RemoteHostTask.doRun(RemoteHostTask.java:279)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.webDeployment.actions.createproject.CreateWebProjectWizard$3.run(CreateWebProjectWizard.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$9.run(CoreProgressManager.java:384)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:555)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-31 16:34:55,222 [11533661]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - PhpStorm 2016.2.1  Build #PS-162.1447.5 
2016-07-31 16:34:55,222 [11533661]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - JDK: 1.8.0_76-release 
2016-07-31 16:34:55,222 [11533661]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - VM: OpenJDK Server VM 
2016-07-31 16:34:55,222 [11533661]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2016-07-31 16:34:55,222 [11533661]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - OS: Windows 10`

Comment: So .. what does `idea.log` has to say about it? Sorry, but on Saturdays/Sunday all remote-mind-reading helms are locked in safe place with no personal allowed.

Comment: Well sorry mister "remote-mind-reading helms are locked in safe place" I'm new to this IDE so i thoug this is something common or I done something wrong. Updated with log entries, I din't know they exist till now.

Comment: Try next 2016.2.1 EAP build or 2016.2.1 final (whatever will become available next). Exception log looks similar to recently fixed ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32519

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug. I'm using phpstorm for like 2 years and i can tell you for sure - that is not supposed to be like that.
I've noticed it too, but i thought it's something wrong with my environment (looks like it's not, lol).

- when creating new project from existing files via ftp, after mapping
  a remote folder as "`project root`" every child folder should be highlighted
  as "to be downloaded", with green background color - at this moment
  it's broken, not entirely, but it is just visual effects.
- second part - after the download process is finished - the project should be opened in new window - that's broken also.
  It does not open new project's window + does not create folder `.idea` inside local project folder. That's not entirely broken - you can "workaround" it.

**Solution (at the moment)** - 
**make sure, that your 'root path' directory is not the same as 'project root'.**

For example:

- you have ftp access to `/var/www/userX/`
- website docroot is located in `/var/www/userX/websiteName/public_html/` (or /www/, whatever)
- you pick `/websiteName/` as `root path` in ftp server's settings screen -  (settings -> building, execution, deplyment -> deployment - remote server settings) - **instead of /websiteName/public_html/** as usual
- when choosing `project root` in wizard - you pick `/public_html/` (**instead of '/' as usual**) - and this is the trick.

Now, when you have selected your 'project root' (which is not the same as 'root path') - step back (`click previous in wizard`), and then `select your ftp server` (yes, again) and `click next`.

Now you can see your remote project tree is highlighted with green background color - choose folders you dont want to be downloaded (exclude from download) - and then repeat the back-and-forth move (previous-next in wizard).

After this you can see your remote project tree is highlighted correctly, and you can proceed "next". After collecting and downloading files your project will be opened as it should.

If it didnt help - restart phpstorm and repeat the creating of project again, selecting the same destination folder - at this time, locally existing files will not be downloaded twice, so it will be faster.